# How to creat a dataframe of columns each with 'n' empty values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to create a dataframe of empty values. My code is

```
df['Voc_inIV'] = np.nan
df['Isc_inIV'] = np.nan
df['Voc_error'] = np.nan
df['Isc_error'] = np.nan
df['Pmpp_inIV'] = np.nan
df['ff'] = np.nan
df['v_at_Isc'] = np.nan
df['i_at_voc'] = np.nan
```

My above approach works. But this does not look good. 
Is there a better approach than this? I mean, I did not like repeating `np.nan` all the times. Moreover, my dataframe should have `n` rows.

Answer (score 1):

To create an empty dataframe, just don't pass any data to the `data` argument, but pass your column names  to `columns`:

```
cols = ['Voc_inIV','Isc_inIV','Voc_error','Isc_error','Pmpp_inIV','ff','v_at_Isc','i_at_voc']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
```

Giving you:

```
>>> df
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Voc_inIV, Isc_inIV, Voc_error, Isc_error, Pmpp_inIV, ff, v_at_Isc, i_at_voc]
Index: []
```

**Edit**: If you need it to have `n` rows, pass an index of `range(n)`:

```
n = 5

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols, index=range(n))

>>> df
  Voc_inIV Isc_inIV Voc_error Isc_error Pmpp_inIV   ff v_at_Isc i_at_voc
0      NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN      NaN      NaN
1      NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN      NaN      NaN
2      NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN      NaN      NaN
3      NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN      NaN      NaN
4      NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN      NaN      NaN
```

Comment: But, how to assign a predefined size to df?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach, helping you specifically with *not repeating `np.nan`*:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
cols = ['Voc_inIV', 'Isc_inIV', 'Voc_error', 'Isc_error', 'Pmpp_inIV', 'ff', 'v_at_Isc', 'i_at_voc']
for col in range(len(cols)):
    df[cols[col]] = np.nan
```